# Get first element of list type data field

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with cells that contain lists.
Now I want to get every first element in the list, if there is one.
Like

```
416                      []
417                      []
419                   [562]
425              [570, 632]
426                      []
427    [511, 586, 753, 604]
428                      []
```

And what I want is a something like this (which can be used i.e. to create a new row)

```
416                    nan
417                    nan
419                    562
425                    570
426                    nan
427                    511
428                    nan
```

How can I do this? Or is this bad practice and should be avoided?

Comment: Just do:

`df[col].apply(lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: There is no such thing as a list-type data field in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['col'].str[0]
```

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': {0: [],
  1: [],
  2: [562],
  3: [570, 632],
  4: [],
  5: [511, 586, 753, 604],
  6: []}})

print(df['col'].str[0])

0      NaN
1      NaN
2    562.0
3    570.0
4      NaN
5    511.0
6      NaN
```